# content with height 100%

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a view with two cols, I want the first col with 80% of the window height and the second with 20%.

I've tried this:

```
<ion-view title="Events" >
    <ion-content >
        <div style="height: 80%;">
            Image here!
        </div>
        <div style="height: 20%;">
            Text here!
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Is not working because this will only work if I had a container with a height in `px` but I can't do that because the height will change according to each device.

Create screens with no scroll with the content fitting the screen height is a common approach and I think ionic should have a documented solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

```
<ion-view title="Events" >
    <ion-content >
        <div style="height: 80vh;">
            Image here!
        </div>
        <div style="height: 20vh;">
            Text here!
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`80vh` is 80% of the height of the viewport.  The same goes for `20vh`.  My answer is also assuming you have correctly set some other CSS "fixes" to make both divs stack vertically without spaces between them, etc.

Comment: this is safe? I'm coding an app to export and run as native Android app

Comment: I read your link now, Will not work for me because I will run on Android 4.0 or greater.